# How can I upload my python trading bot to the internet for auto-trading?

Tags: python, trading, algorithmic-trading

I have written a python code that I can run it on my computer. It gets stock data from a website by `GET` request. Then it does some calculations on upon these online data and decides to send a `buy/sell` request to my broker's account.

All of these works fine on my computer, but I like to upload my code on a web server to preventing electricity/internet disconnection. I think I should upload my code on a virtual server, but this is all the thing I know and I don't have more experience or knowledge about it. I don't know if it is what I need, how can I do that?

In my experience of making some simple web pages, we should put our main code inside the `public.html` file? So should I buy a web host and wrap my python code inside a `.html` file?

Sorry if they are simple/stupid questions but I couldn't find any answer or guidence for doung what I want, so I asked here!

Comment: If you really know nothing about how this works, my suggestion would be don't do it, there's a big chance that you'll end up with security issues. E.g. how do you send the request to your broker's account? Via e-mail? Or do you have any credentials hardcoded in your script? Is the information that you get available on public websites or do you log into them to access it?

Comment: @ChatterOne: I use `Selenium` web automation program to open my brokers web page, then I enter my user, pass, and the CAPTCHA by hand, then my python code will filling the forms to buy/sell stocks. Is this unsecure you think?

Comment: If you enter your credentials by hand, in the browser running on your local PC, how do you expect it to be actually working on a remote machine? There will be no browser on the remote machine that your script will be able to control. (There could be if you put it there, but you don't want to go down that path. You also don't want the remote machine to control your local one)

Comment: @ChatterOne: What I wanted to do is just preventing electricity drop or internet disconnection on my local PC. I know I can buy a UPS and maybe have two internet connections, one of them as bypass, but I thought uploading my codes on a server may could be a more reliable way. But you are right, I must install a chrome on VPS then I start my program everyday by hand, because I must enter my credentials by hand!

Answer (score 1):

With the info you provide I can't really be sure how your script is ran.
I presume you run it by shell in that case a simple vps should suffice.
No need to mess around with a webserver.

Maybe look at [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/pricing/#Compute). They are a market leader and the simple $5 option probably enough for your purpose.

When you set it up you can connect to it with ssh ([preferably with a ssh key because you are working with financial data](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2)) and setup your python script as if it were your own computer.

Ps. I don't work for digital ocean or get money from the link. It is just an example, any vps will work.

Comment: i use Vultr for my python scripts. The cheapest one is 2.5$ per month that is sufficiently  powerful for running one or two scripts